# Upload multiple images to firebase storage and then view all download URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-storage

I have an array of images. I upload each individual image to Firebase Storage after klcik on a button and then put the DownloadURL in an array. I would like to display this array once all the images have been uploaded. The problem is that when I set a breakpoint at Promise.all, I don't see all the images in the array, but only maybe the first 3 out of 5. Only after reloading the browser do I see the rest. How can I wait until all DownloadURLS are really in the array?

```
const uploadAllImages = async () => {
let array = [];
const promises = [];
try {
  for (let i = 0; i < previews.length; i++) {
    const fileName = uuidv4() + ".jpg";
    const storageRef = ref(
      storage,
      `${currentUser.email}/images/` + fileName
    );

    const filesForUpload = await uploadString(
      storageRef,
      previews[i],
      "data_url"
    ).then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then(async (url) => {
        array.push(url);
      });
    });

    promises.push(filesForUpload);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

await Promise.all(promises)
  .then(() => {
    console.log(array);
    setUploadedImages(array);
  })
  .then(() => //Set to true elsewhere  setLoading(false));
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a couple of things problematic in the snipped.
Mainly async await vs. Promise.then syntax.

In an async function we are able to await on promises. When a promise is invoked after `await`. The code will not continue its execution until the promise is resolved. Furthermore we can try{}catch{} the errors

If in a synchronous function, the way to handle promises, and force a somewhat synchronous behaviour, is to use the Promise callback methods `new Promise.then().error().finally...`. That allows us to execute callback functions after the promise is either resolved or rejected.

In your snippet the two concepts are used interchangeably which is what I assume has gone wrong here.

So a proposed solution to this could for example be to write it like this

```js
const uploadAllImages = async () => {
  let array = [];
  const promises = [];

  const uploadFile = async (storageRef, preview) => {
    const snapshot = await uploadString(storageRef, preview, "data_url");
    const url = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
    array.push(url);
  }

  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < previews.length; i++) {
      const fileName = uuidv4() + ".jpg";
      const storageRef = ref(
        storage,
        `${currentUser.email}/images/` + fileName
      );
  
      promises.push(uploadFile(storageRef, previews[i]));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  
  await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(array);
  setUploadedImages(array);
};
```

Edit, one thing to add to that. Calling asynchronous functions without the await keyword, will return a promise. Calling them with the await keyword will return the functions return statement